# calculate mode in R wrt other column

Tags: r, data-analysis

This question is not duplicate of following question :
Is there a built-in function for finding the mode? [Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode)
All the answers mentioned on above link find mode for a single column or a vector. Whereas I want to find mode wrt to other column

I have data like this :-

```
Col1 Col2
C    High
B    Small
C    Medium
B    High
D    Medium
B    Medium
B    Small
B    Medium
B    Small
B    High
B    Small
C    Medium
B    Medium
D    High
B    Small
B    High
D    High
```

I want to find mode and result should look as follows:-

```
col1  Mode 
B     Small
C     Medium
D     High
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you actually try to achieve? I can't understand how you got that result without further explanation.

Comment: which value from col2 occurs maximum number of time for each unique value in col1. Like for B, Value small occurred maximum number of times . Similarly for C and D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` library:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, .N, by = list(Col1, Col2)][, .SD[which.max(N)], by = Col1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
df[,.(Mode = names(which.max(table(Col2)))), by = Col1]

   Col1   Mode
1:    C Medium
2:    B  Small
3:    D   High
```

Very similar solution, will just leave it here for reference.

Comment: You could also do this in base R: `aggregate(Col2 ~ Col1, data = df, function(x) names(which.max(table(x))))`

Comment: @jaap thanks . simplest solution